# BlockUI spinner not loading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, blockui

I have a page, that when the user clicks a button, I use 'blockUI' (http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)  to show a modal message saying, 'Sending' with a spinner.

```
$('#btnSend').click(function () {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h4><img src="http://www.example.com/images/busy.gif" /> Sending email...</h4>' });
});
```

When I copy that URL into a browser, I see the spinning image. However, on the site, it shows an invalid image placeholder, as if the image file isn't there, or it's an invalid URL.

When I 'view source' and copy the URL on the page into a new browser, it works fine. Do I somehow have to pre-load the image?

Comment: works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/Taw83/82/

Comment: Thanks, that works for me too - but on my page it just won't load. See http://www.accufinance.com/ContactUs/Contact ... I can't see why it won't work. I have the same as you, but the icon just won't load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Add `<img src="http://www.accufinance.com/images/busy.gif" id="loader"/>` inside your body tag. Also add this in your css file.

```
#loader{
    display: none;
}
```

You should change your blockUI code to

> $.blockUI({ message: $('#loader') });

Make sure your  tag is above your $.blockUI script.

**PS:** I hope you are not using absolute paths like `http://www.accu....../busy.gif` and you are using something like `/images/busy.gif`

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I added this piece of code from the console on your website

```
$('body').append('<img src="http://www.accufinance.com/images/busy.gif"/>');
```

After that gif works perfectly. So the form is submitted before the image could be downloaded. Have the gif in the dom instead of dynamically downloading it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the gif to the dom. Can you assist?

Comment: Thanks! Going to try that now. And no. Not using absolute paths. That was me just making sure my path want the issue. :-)